The Klausenburger Rebbe's speech and Zionism
In the new book on the Klausenburger Rebbe, "The Klausenburger Rebbe
Building Torah and Emunah in the Aftermath of the Holocaust", the famous story is told about when (the then) General Eisenhower visited the DP-camp "Feldafing" just after liberation in 1945. The book (pp. 170-171) recounts the quiet battle between the majority of the survivors, and some of the secular Jews who represented various Zionist and socialist organizations:

At that juncture there was a quiet battle between the majority of the survivors, and some of the secular Jews who represented various Zionist and socialist organizations. Whereas the majority of the survivors felt it would be appropriate for the Rebbe to address the ceremony as the voice of the survivors, the secular Jews who represented various Zionist and socialist organizations refused to let him speak unless he promised that he would not mention G-d's Name, or anything related to religion.

The bibliography mentions "Sanz, Issue 487" in describing this event. I now have access to this issue, with thanks to the publisher(s). But I am rephrasing the question :)
What were these groups of "secular Jews, or Zionists" that would not want the Rebbe mention G-ds name? What was their deal in not wanting to mention G-ds name, and where did they/their ideology come from?

It was a newspaper of the Sanzer chassidus

@Dov What was the full title of the newspaper? Where was the newspaper published? When did it publish?

I don't know more than that @Deuteronomy, hence the comment. The other biography (Feldheim) written by Judah Lifschitz also quotes extensively from it...

@Dov OK... seemed evident that it was a Sanzer periodical of sorts. Thanks anyhow.

For the record this story is recorded also in the Feldheim book pp.173-175. The footnote attributes the report to Yehoshua Veitzenblum if you want to do some detective work...

@Dov thanks for your research in that it was a newspaper. Do you maybe know if this was a physical distributed newspaper, or also a digital one? If it was a newspaper from back to the 60's for example, that would explain why no copies can be found online when searching for it :)

@Dov and yes, my copy from ArtScroll also mentions these newspapers a loooooot.

It also does not showup at the newspaper-list here.

I doubt they had digital papers in those days :-) - I think you are referring to if it has been digitally archived. Sadly, I couldn't tell you.

@Dov exactly, that is what I meant :) I don't know if there are Klausenburg Chasidim here on Mi Yodeya, but I am searching further :)

The Sanz Chassidus in Netanya publishes a monthly newspaper which is the what is meant here. BTW, if mupy memory serves me right the you can find the same story in Lapid Haeish (the original biography). In there there will be a better source than the newspaper

@Yoreinu thanks. I contacted the publisher of the Sanz newspaper, and they sent me a pdf of that issue. I also read that it is in Lapid HaEish yes, so I immediately ordered it :) Thanks though!

@Shmuel did you order the Hebrew version? I think the English version is a bit shortened. In any case, I do not belive that the organization's are identified in the book.

@Yoreinu Yes, Lapid HaEish Hebrew version from Shefa Chaim (the orginial Klausenberg publisher).

The Torah journal to which you are likely referring is called "צאנז, תורה, עבודה וגמילות חסדים" and is listed in the National Library of Israel catalog here.
It is available in the library in print.  From searching on the NLI site and also on Hebrew Books and Otzar HaChochma, it seems that it isn't currently digitized or available for reading online.
If you click on the "Show Location" link for that item, you will get a popup that lists over 500 issues for that journal from the year 5736 (1975-76) through the present.  The issue #487 you mention was published in 5778 (2017-18).

Wow, thank you very much. When I click on order, will I get it online, or does the library in Israel reserve it for me, since I am not able to pick it up (living abroad).

@Shmuel I posted the "Show Location" link only to show the list of volumes that were published.  If you click "order" that would only be for in-library use as reference material. So for your purposes, maybe only good for next time you're in Israel unless you have a friend or family member who  can go there and look up what you want.
